# Java android killed service when application is killed or close

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, service

I want to **kill my service when I close(killed) my application** : this is my service :

In this service I have an asyntask, which will start working again just like this :

```
   TimerTask myTimerTask = new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    connectTask3 = new connectTask3();
                    connectTask3.execute();
                }

            };
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 2000);
```

how I can stop this service at asyntask when an application is close ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want stop the asynctask you can use `asyncTask.cancel(true/false);`

`true` specifies the android system to stop this service even it had already started,

`false` specifies the android system not to stop this task if it has already started.

---

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    timer.cancel();
    connectTask3.cancel(true);

}
```

if you want stop this service when the activity looses its interaction write it in `onPause()`
    or 
    if you want to cancel at the time of activity destroy call it in `onDestroy()`

for more details please [check AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: although OP has written about service in the question but actually question is not related to service but timer task

Comment: He is not using services but asynctask and timer task.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your manifest

```
<service android:name="service" android:stopWithTask="true"/>
```

stopwithtask will stop the service when app is closed or killed

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    timer.cancel(true);   //stops timerTask
    connectTask3.cancel(); //stops asynctask
    super.onDestroy();
}
```